# Does PHP have an equivalent to Python's list comprehension syntax?

Tags: php, arrays, list-comprehension, higher-order-functions, language-comparisons

Python has syntactically sweet list comprehensions:

```
S = [x**2 for x in range(10)]
print S;
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

In PHP I would need to do some looping:

```
$output = array();
$Nums = range(0,9);

foreach ($Nums as $num) 
{
    $out[] = $num*=$num;
}
print_r($out);
```

to get:

Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 9
    [4] => 16
    [5] => 25
    [6] => 36
    [7] => 49
    [8] => 64
    [9] => 81
)

Is there anyway to get a similar list comprehension syntax in PHP? Is there anyway to do it with any of the new features in PHP 5.3?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd say an even better example of how awesome python list comprehensions are is the conditionals!

x = [x*2 for x in range(1,9) if x < 3] or whatever
Bet that can't be done with array map!

Comment: **See also:** passing variables into anonymous function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420520/php-variables-in-anonymous-functions

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
$out=array_map(function($x) {return $x*$x;}, range(0, 9))
```

This will work in PHP 5.3+, in an older version you'd have to define the callback for [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) separately

```
function sq($x) {return $x*$x;}
$out=array_map('sq', range(0, 9));
```

Comment: Nice answer. +1. Not exactly list comprehension, but it's a very elegant and short solution nevertheless. Have a care tho, this is PHP 5.3+ since an anonymous function is used.

Comment: PHP 5.3 required. But nice solution :)

Comment: create_function() could probably be used with PHP < 5.3

Comment: you could use create_function, but it looks bloody ugly - far clearer just to define a new function IMHO!

Comment: Wow, very elegant! Another reason to upgrade to 5.3. Thanks!

Comment: For comprehensions are a convenience over map, reduce and filter operations. For that matter between array_map, array_reduce, and array_filter you could have everything, a thin library using the __invoke() magic method and you could get a full on _pretty_ functional API.

Comment: Can you use this with A constructor? `array_map("new MyClass", range(0,9))`?

Comment: Actually this is not list comprehension. (Python has `map` function too.) Though `map` and list comprehension are similar.

Comment: this is not the same thing. take, for instance, this list comprehension: [x for x in collection if x.meetsCondition()]

Answer (score 6):

PHP 5.5 may support list comprehensions - see the mailing list announcement:

- [[PHP-DEV] List comprehensions and generator expressions for PHP](http://markmail.org/thread/uvendztpe2rrwiif) (28 Jun 2012)

And further discussion:

- [What Generators Can Do For You](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/07/what-generators-can-do-for-you.html) (by ircmaxell; 23 Jul 2012) - has a Fibonacci example.
- [What PHP 5.5 might look like](http://nikic.github.com/2012/07/10/What-PHP-5-5-might-look-like.html#generators) (by NikiC; 10 Jul 2012)
- [Request for Comments: Generators](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generators) (Wiki started 05 Jun 2012)

Comment: For those reading this comment now: PHP 5.5 (or 5.6) didn't include list comprehensions. It did include generators.

Comment: What about PHP 7?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think PHP7 added anything regarding list comprehensions.

Answer (score 2):

not out of the box, but take a look at:
http://code.google.com/p/php-lc/ or http://code.google.com/p/phparrayplus/

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP 7.4 you can also use *[arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php)* in `array_map`:

```
<?php

$nums = range(0,9);
print_r(array_map(fn($x) => $x*$x,$nums));

// Array
// (
//     [0] => 0
//     [1] => 1
//     [2] => 4
//     [3] => 9
//     [4] => 16
//     [5] => 25
//     [6] => 36
//     [7] => 49
//     [8] => 64
//     [9] => 81
// )
```

[See live](https://3v4l.org/5KhFY)

Answer (score -2):

In .NET, the equivalent of Python's "syntactically sweet list comprehensions" is LINQ. And in PHP, there're several ports of it, including [YaLinqo](https://github.com/Athari/YaLinqo) library*. Syntactically, it's closer to SQL rather than a sequence of traditional constructs with `for` and `if`, but functionally, it's similar:

```
$a = Enumerable::range(0, 10)->select('$v * $v');
```

This produces an iterator which can either be output to console:

```
var_dump($a->toArray()); // by transforming the iterator to an array
echo $a->toString(', '); // or by imploding into a string
```

or iterated over using `foreach`:

```
foreach ($a as $i)
    echo $i, PHP_EOL;
```

Here, `'$v * $v'` is a shortcut for `function ($v) { return $v * $v; }` which this library supports. Unfortunately, PHP doesn't support short syntax for closures, but such "string lambdas" can be used to make the code shorter.

There're many more methods, starting with `where` (`if` equivalent) and ending with `groupJoin` which performs joining transformation with grouping.

<sub>* developed by me</sub>