# Can PHP be more like python?

Tags: php, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does PHP have an equivalent to Python's list comprehension syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266911/does-php-have-an-equivalent-to-pythons-list-comprehension-syntax)

Does PHP have any equivalent of the simple and awesome list comprehension in python? Specifically, can I do `a = [x for x in xrange(1,20)]` in PHP w/o annoying loops?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266911/does-php-have-an-equivalent-to-pythons-list-comprehension-syntax

Comment: Short answer is "no." Some things can be done easily (see my answer, see the duplicate question) others cannot. PHP isn't Python, and please don't try to force it to be something it's not!

Answer (score 2):

I think this will set you free: http://code.google.com/p/php-lc/

Comment: Bandaid over a bullet hole. http://bit.ly/bM1Teu

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the python 'x for x in xrange' a loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = range(1,19);
```