# Modify a globally scoped variable inside of an anonymous function

Tags: php, function, global-variables, pass-by-reference, anonymous

I was playing around with anonymous functions in PHP and realized that they don't seem to reach variables outside of them.
Is there any way to get around this problem?

Example:

```
$variable = "nothing";

functionName($someArgument, function() {
  $variable = "something";
});

echo $variable;  //output: "nothing"
```

This will output "nothing". Is there any way that the anonymous function can access the `$variable`?

Answer (score 371, accepted):

Yes, [use a closure](http://php.net/closure):

```
functionName($someArgument, function() use(&$variable) {
  $variable = "something";
});
```

Note that in order for you to be able to modify `$variable` and retrieve the modified value outside of the scope of the anonymous function, it must be referenced in the closure using `&`.