# Want to get sub category products in cakephp 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have category table with tree structures and products table. I want to show on listing. when user click parent category I want to show all products of this category and products of sub-category of this category too.

```
 public function listing($catid = null, $slug = null)
    {
        $this->viewBuilder()->layout('frontview');
        $this->loadModel('Categories');
        $this->loadModel('Products');        
        $categoryid=$this->Categories->find('children',['for'=>$catid]);
        $catarray=array();
        foreach($categoryid as $c) {
            $catarray[]=$c['categoryId'];
        }
        debug($catarray);
        $products=$this->Products->find()
            ->where(function ($exp, $q) {
        return $exp->in('categories_id',$catarray); //line 81
    });
       $this->set('products',$products);

    }
```

debug of $catarray is

```
[
    (int) 0 => (int) 6,
    (int) 1 => (int) 7,
    (int) 2 => (int) 8,
    (int) 3 => (int) 9,
    (int) 4 => (int) 10,
    (int) 5 => (int) 11,
    (int) 6 => (int) 12
]
```

Errors :Notice (8): Undefined variable: catarray [APP/Controller\CategoriesController.php, line 81] 
Errors : Impossible to generate condition with empty list of values for field (categories_id)

Comment: That notice is caused by it not being passed to the anonymous function. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420520/php-variables-in-anonymous-functions

Answer (score 0):

as stated by Sevvlor you have to do

```
function ($exp, $q) uses(catarray)
```

but you can also simplify your code doing:

```
$categoryid=$this->Categories->find('children',['for'=>$catid]);
$catarray = $categoryid->extract('categoryId');
$products=$this->Products->find()
    ->where(['category_id IN' => $catarray]);
```