# Why can I not acces my variable in this eloquent database call method?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to build a search functionality in my laravel app. I want to search on the name of a tag that is related with a pivot table to my loops. But I get the error *'undefined variable : query'*

This is my controller method :

```
public function search($query) {

    $searchResult = Loop::whereHas('tags', function ($q) {
                $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $query .'%');  
            })->get(); 

    return Response::json($searchResult);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php variables in anonymous functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420520/php-variables-in-anonymous-functions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass `$query` variable into a closure with `use()`, like this:

```
$searchResult = Loop::whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($query) {
            $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $query .'%');  
        })->get();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php (check example #3)

Comment: I was looking for something like that for a while! I can't thank you enough!

Comment: Glad I could help. )