# Variable Scope with Async PHP (Guzzle)

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I'm trying to use Guzzle async requests to populate an object's properties based on an api response.

How would I access an object like `$myObj` below, inside the response handler to operate on?

As is, `$myObj` is not reachable. I did find when working inside a class, `$this` is accessible from within the response handler, but I'm hoping there's another way.

```
$myObj;

$promise = $this->client->requestAsync('GET', 'http://example.com/api/someservice');
$promise->then(
  function (ResponseInterface $res) {
    $data = json_decode($res->getBody());

    // How can I access vars like $myObj from here?
    $myObj->setName($data->name);
    // ... then persist to db
  },
  function (RequestException $e) {

  }
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php variables in anonymous functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420520/php-variables-in-anonymous-functions)

Comment: You will get answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62483009/10302693)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP doesn't import variable in a function context by default. You should use `use` to explicitly list variables that you want to import.

```
function (ResponseInterface $res) use ($myObj) {
    $data = json_decode($res->getBody());

    // How can I access vars like $myObj from here?
    $myObj->setName($data->name);
    // ... then persist to db
},
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try to make the $myObj global. For example add the line: `global $myObj;` above the line: `$data = json_decode($res->getBody());`