# How to access Guzzle's fullfilled response outside its scope?

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am new to guzzle package and I am sending async post requests through it using pool-promise method. Everything is well and good but once the request is fulfilled and response is received, I am trying to store some part of json response in an array  `$arr`.

```
$client = new Client();

        $arr = [];


        $requests = function ($total) use ($client) {

            $request_headers = [
                'api_key' => config('app.wallet_server_api_key'),
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            ];


            $form_params = [
                'accounts' => 0,
                'totalaccounts' => 100,
            ];


            $uri = 'MY_REQUEST_URL_CAN_NOT_DISCLOSE';


            for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
//                yield new Request('POST', $uri, $request_headers, http_build_query($form_params, null, '&'));

                yield function () use ($client, $uri, $request_headers, $form_params) {
                    return $client->postAsync($uri, [
                        'headers' => $request_headers,
                        'form_params' => $form_params
                    ]);
                };
            }


        };

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests(2), [
            'concurrency' => 5,
            'fulfilled' => function (Response $response, $index) use ($arr) {
                // Response is logged successfully
                Log::info(json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true)['message']);

                // I am pushing the message key from json response received but it is not taking
                $arr[] = json_decode((string)$response->getBody()->getContents(), true)['message'];


            },
            'rejected' => function (RequestException $reason, $index) {
                // this is delivered each failed request
                Log::warning(json_encode($reason->getMessage()));
            },
        ]);

// Initiate the transfers and create a promise
        $promise = $pool->promise();

// Force the pool of requests to complete.
        $promise->wait();

dd($arr); // Displays as null
```

Please help me understand its working.

EDIT: using postman, I am getting response in json format like below:

```
{"status":true,"message":"Mnemonics fetched successfully",....SOME OTHER KEYS ETC }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question as I found the solution.

If you want to **set** variable in anonymous function, use `&$VariableName` as in my case it is:

```
'fulfilled' => function (Response $response, $index) use (&$arr) {  // <-- see the & sign here
                // Response is logged successfully
                Log::info(json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true)['message']);

                // I am pushing the message key from json response received but it is not taking
                $arr[] = json_decode((string)$response->getBody()->getContents(), true)['message'];


            },
```

I hope someone like me will fond this answer useful.