# How to write sql multi tables join query in Cakephp 3?

Tags: sql, cakephp-3.0, join

I have this Query in Sql giving me required course_path but I am not able to implement this in Cakephp 3 although I have created relations between these tables in Cakephp Model.

```
  SELECT c.course_path
  FROM courses c
  JOIN modules m ON c.id = m.course_id
  JOIN topics t ON m.id = t.module_id
  WHERE t.topic_name = 'test_topic'.
```

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799094/how-to-filter-by-conditions-for-associated-models**

Comment: Thanks a lot @ndm. This link solved my problem :)

Comment: Still one question- How can I pass a variable instead of fixed value in the Query-   
      $this->Contacts
      ->find()
      ->contain('Users')
      ->matching('Users', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $q) {
        return $q->where(['Users.id' => 1]);
     });

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420520/php-variables-in-anonymous-functions**