# cross join arrays to generate data for test scenarios

Tags: php

I'm trying to cross join arrays to automatically create data for various test scenarios in an app.  Here are the arrays to be cross joined (note that `$base['sales']` has had some elements stripped out of it to simplify it for posting this question):

```
$base['sales'] = ['shirts'=>1200.0, 'pants'=>1000.0, 'socks'=>1700.0];

$scenarioIDs = range(1, 5);
```

The end result is supposed to look like this:

```
$data[1]['sales'] = ['shirts'=>1200.0, 'pants'=>1000.0, 'socks'=>1700.0];
$data[2]['sales'] = ['shirts'=>1200.0, 'pants'=>1000.0, 'socks'=>1700.0];
$data[3]['sales'] = ['shirts'=>1200.0, 'pants'=>1000.0, 'socks'=>1700.0];
$data[4]['sales'] = ['shirts'=>1200.0, 'pants'=>1000.0, 'socks'=>1700.0];
$data[5]['sales'] = ['shirts'=>1200.0, 'pants'=>1000.0, 'socks'=>1700.0];
```

I have tried this:

```
    $data = [];
    array_map(function($scenarioID) {
        $data[$scenarioID]['sales'] = $base['sales'];
    }, $scenarioIDs);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($data, 1) . '</pre>';    
exit();
```

but get the message `Undefined variable: base in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sales\index.php on line 72` five times (one for each scenarioID).

I keep thinking there must be a way to do this without using loops.  Does anyone know how?

Comment: `function($scenarioIDs) use ($base) {...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php variables in anonymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420520/php-variables-in-anonymous-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a variable from the exterior context within your anonymous function, you need the `use` keyword:

```
array_map(
  function($id) use ($base, &$data) {/* fill out the function */},
  $scenarioIDs
);
```

This syntax will make a copy of `$base` at the time the function is first invoked, so if you make changes to `$base` and try to use the same custom mapper, the new values of `$base` will not be reflected. So, if you need the anonymous function to always work with the current value of `$base`, then pass that argument by reference as I did with `$data`:

```
function($id) use (&$base, &$data) {}
```

[From the docs:](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the *use* language construct.

As a sidenote, `array_map` is meant to transform the supplied array (`$scenarioIDs` in your case) into a different array.  You aren't really using it as it was meant. If all you want to do is attach the scenario ids as keys to `$data`, just use this one-liner:

```
foreach($scenarioIDs as $id) $data[$id]['sales'] = $base['sales'];
```