# Setting a global variable's value inside an anonymous function

Tags: php, closures, global-variables, anonymous-function

I am using [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) to crawl a site. I am trying to set the `$node->text()` value to a global variable, `$myGlobalVar`, inside the `->each(function ($node) {..});` anonymous function.

```
$myGlobalVar = '';

$crawler->filter('.the-link-class')->each(function ($node) {
    if($myGlobalVar == ''){
        print "using first " . $node->text() . "\n";
        $myGlobalVar = $node->text();            
    }
});

print "myGlobalVar: " . $myGlobalVar . "\n"; # always empty !!!!!!
```

I have also tried the `use(&$myGlobalVar)` closure syntax that was suggested in this [answer I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420520/php-variables-in-anonymous-functions).  When I modify the relevant code to `->each(function use(&$myGlobalVar) ($node) {..` I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is invalid.

Please change from:

```
->each(function use(&$myGlobalVar) ($node) {..
```

to:

```
->each(function ($node) use(&$myGlobalVar) {..
```

Also, If the variable `$myGlobalVar` is declared in the global scope, then you can use the [global](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword to directly access and modify the variable