# PHP Get most repeated value in Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array within an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => B
            [id] => 924572
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => A
            [id] => 120689
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => A 
            [id] => 120689
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => C
            [id] => 919644
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => A
            [id] => 120689
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => B
            [id] => 924572
        )
)
```

How can I get the most repeated value from object named `name` and `id`?

I've already tried the code below but I'm getting an error: `Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!`

```
$count = array_count_values($info);
arsort($count);
$popular = array_keys($count);
echo $popular[0];
```

Any fix regarding to this problem?

Comment: @jayant this is php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Serializing way" for searching most repeated couples (`name`,`id`):

```
$out = array();
foreach($arr as $el){
   $key = serialize($el);
   if (!isset($out[$key]))
       $out[$key]=1;
   else
       $out[$key]++;
}

arsort($out);

foreach($out as $el=>$count){
   $item = unserialize($el);
   echo "Name = ".$item['name'].' ID = '.$item['id'].' Count = '.$count.'<br/>';
}
```

Output:

```
Name = A ID = 120689 Count = 3
Name = B ID = 924572 Count = 2
Name = C ID = 919644 Count = 1
```

**update** Without loop

```
.....
arsort($out);

$most  = unserialize(key($out));
$most_count = array_shift($out);

echo $most['name'];
echo $most['id'];
echo $most_count;
```

Output:

```
A
120689
3
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far! Thank you! Let me ask a question. How can I display first result without using `foreach($out as $el=>$count)`? I've tried to used echo `$out[1]` but nothing displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [finding the mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036114/how-to-find-the-mode-of-an-array-in-php) and [mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266911/does-php-have-an-equivalent-to-pythons-list-comprehension-syntax) in PHP. Would this work?

```
$name_array = array_map(function($x) {return $x["name"];}, $info);
$count = array_count_values($name_array);
$mode = array_keys($count, max($count));
```

To return an array of `"name"`, `"id"` pairs use:

```
$return_value = array_filter($info, function($x) use ($mode) { return (in_array($x["name"], $mode));});
```

Comment: There's still an error "Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values! "

Comment: Sorry I was accessing the array elements incorrectly. I have fixed my answer to use `$x["name"]`

Comment: @tokis yes. Updated my answer to return all values

Comment: That's great! Thanks! But is it possible to also add the "id" object in array?

Comment: @tokis use `array_filter` and `in_array` as updated in my answer

Comment: I've noticed that your updated code only returns one result: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=vAkMKtx6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94480/discussion-between-jayant-and-tokis).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can work with this solution:

```
<?php
$info = array(
    array(
        "name" => "B",
        "id" => 924572
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "A",
        "id" => 120689
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "A",
        "id" => 120689
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "C",
        "id" => 919644
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "A",
        "id" => 120689
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "B",
        "id" => 924572
    ),
);

$result = array();
foreach ($info as $infoKey => $infoValue) {
    foreach ($infoValue as $itemKey => $itemValue) {
        if ($itemKey != "name") {
            continue;
        }
        if (array_key_exists($itemValue, $result)){
            $result[$itemValue]++;
            continue;
        }
        $result[$itemValue] = 1;
    }
}
arsort($result);
var_dump($result);
```

Will result in:

```
array (size=3)
  'A' => int 3
  'B' => int 2
  'C' => int 1
```

Comment: It only returns: array(0) { }

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to add the array itself. Updated the code.

Comment: Nice! Your code works well! But is it possible to also add the "id" object in array?

Answer (score 1):

A more linear solution.

```
$arr = Array
(
    Array
        (
            "name" => "B",
            "id" => 924572
        ),

    Array
        (
            "name" => "A",
            "id" => 120689
        ),

    Array
        (
            "name" => "A" ,
            "id" => 120689
        ),

    Array
        (
            "name" => "C",
            "id" => 919644
        ),

    Array
        (
            "name" => "A",
            "id" => 120689
        ),

    Array
        (
            "name" => "B",
            "id" => 924572
        ));

$countArr = Array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
{
    $tmpArr = $arr[$i];

    if(array_key_exists($tmpArr["name"],$countArr))
        $countArr[$tmpArr["name"]]++;
    else
        $countArr[$tmpArr["name"]] = 0;
}

arsort($countArr);
var_dump($countArr);
```

Comment: Your code works but in my actual array it doesn't work. Here's my actual array: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Yj1MvTa2

Comment: And what is the difference? i guess name is defined a a string and keys the same way?

Comment: Then it should work, what error do you get on my code?

Comment: Sorry. Your code really works.  Thank you! But is it possible to also add the "id" object in array?

Comment: You want id added to the sorted count result?

Answer (score 1):

Makes use of [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) (requires PHP 5.5 or [shim](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column)).

```
$count_values = array_count_values(array_column($array, 'name'));

$most_frequent_name = array_search(max($count_values), $count_values);
```

Then if you want all arrays with this name:

```
$items = array_filter($array, function ($v) use ($most_frequent_name) {
    return $v['name'] == $most_frequent_name;
});
```

If several names may have the same top frequency:

```
$count_values = array_count_values(array_column($array, 'name'));

$most_frequent_names = array_keys($count_values, max($count_values));

$items = array_filter($array, function ($v) use ($most_frequent_names) {
    return in_array($v['name'], $most_frequent_names);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. It will give you count of occurrences of all elements

```
function array_icount_values($arr,$lower=true) { 
     $arr2=array(); 
     if(!is_array($arr['0'])){$arr=array($arr);} 
     foreach($arr as $k=> $v){ 
      foreach($v as $v2){ 
      if($lower==true) {$v2=strtolower($v2);} 
      if(!isset($arr2[$v2])){ 
          $arr2[$v2]=1; 
      }else{ 
           $arr2[$v2]++; 
           } 
    } 
    } 
    return $arr2; 
} 

$arr = array_icount_values($array);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: It's not sorting from highest to lowest (MOST REPEATED VALUE).